# Tkinter Label not apeared after time sleep

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this problem in tkinter when I created a simple program that shows words from one list and if I click save the word is recorded in another list and a message will appear to tell me if the word is or is not in the second list and go to next word after 40 milliseconds.

But when I applied that idea, next word appears but the message doesn't. Like it was skipped. It appears only if I delete the line

```
time.sleep(0.40)
```

Here is the code I am using

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

lista_index = 0
lista = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6']
saved = []

def next_prev(event, text=''):
    global lista_index
    if text == "next" and lista_index<len(lista)-1:
        lista_index +=1
        print_text()

    elif text == "prev" and lista_index>0:
        lista_index -=1
        print_text()

    elif text == "save":
        word = lista[lista_index]
        if word not in saved:
            saved.append( lista[lista_index] )
            print_text('Saved','green')
        else:
            print_text('Already saved!')

def print_text(message='',color='red'):
    # clear all widgets
    _list = root.winfo_children()
    for item in _list:
        item.grid_forget()

    word = lista[lista_index]
    Label(root,text=message,
          font=('Time New Roman',10,'bold italic'), fg=color).grid(row=0,column=1)

    # SEPARATOR
    Label(root,text='').grid(row=1,column=0)

    # Show Word
    Label(root,text=word,
          font=('Time New Roman',14,'bold'), fg='blue').grid(row=2,column=0)

    # save and go to next word
    if message=='Saved':
        time.sleep(0.40)
        next_prev('','next')

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')

# binding
root.bind("<KeyPress-Right>", lambda event, t="next":  next_prev(event, t))
root.bind("<KeyPress-Left>",  lambda event, t="prev":  next_prev(event, t))
root.bind("<KeyPress-Down>",  lambda event, t="save":  next_prev(event, t))
print_text()
root.mainloop()
```

Why isn't the message displayed when using `time.sleep()`?

> **Copy comment**: This is the new code in function `print_text()`
>
> ```
> def print_text(message='',color='red'): 
>     global label_text
>     label_msg word = lista[lista_index] 
>     label_text.set( word ) 
>     label_text.set(word) 
>     label_msg.set(message) 
>
>     # save and go to next word 
>     if message=='Saved': 
>         time.sleep(0.40) 
>         next_prev('','next')
> ```
>
> The message appear only in the last word.. when `time.sleep(0.40)` and `next_prev('','next')` are not working

Comment: Have you done any research? There are dozens if not hundreds of questions on this site related to tkinter and the use of sleep.

Comment: @stovfl thank you for your help. About what you said:  **doesn't change anything as long as you create new widgets** , in second try i've created 2 labels in the main code and the function ```print_text()``` update contents of widgets with ```textvariable```  instead of creating new widgets every call and again **the same problem is happening**

Comment: @Hasan ***"when ... `next_prev('','next')` are not working"***: Look, when you call `next_prev('','next')` there follows `print_text()` which overwrites `label_msg.set(message)` with the default `message=''`. This happens within `0.4` second.

Comment: @stovfl yah i know thats why i include  ```time.sleep(0.4)``` To prevent the program from going to the next word while the message appears in 0.4 second and then the message will be changed to ' '  and next word will be displayed

Comment: @Hasan ***"i know that"***: So you have not well explaind why do you overwrite the `message` with `""` and insists ***"Why isn't the message displayed?"***

Comment: When command ```save``` is called The message should be changed and remain for 0.4 seconds after executing ```time.sleep(0.4)``` after that the next command ```next_prev('','next')```  will be executed and the next word will be affiched and the message will be reinstalled

Comment: @Hasan ***"and the message will be reinstalled"***: But you don't pass a message from `next_prev('','next')`. No `message`, nothing to display.

Comment: @stovfl i think the problem is that **the program show the final result after executing all comands** that's why the message not displayed. I was wrong when I thought that the program will show the result when ```time.sleep``` is executed

Comment: Its tricky .. My mistake :) the program work well without  **save and go to the next word automatically** but i needed to know why this method is not working. **thank you stovfl, William Miller**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, at least i understand what you are trying to do.
Try this approach, it displays the `message` for a time span of `500` milliseconds.

```
def print_text(message='',color='red'):
    label_word.set(lista[lista_index])

    if message:
        label_msg.set(message)
        root.after(500, lambda: label_msg.set(""))

    # save and go to next word
    if message == 'Saved':
        next_prev('', 'next')
```

Comment: Hhh thank you very much. Worked very well. Sorry i can't  vote and for my bad enlish and